# XSLT XPath first note with attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes, nodes

I want to select the first column without `@type='hidden'` in the first `<xsl:if>`, and the other nodes without `@type='hidden'`  in the second `<xsl:if>`. I only want to give `a` in the first `<xsl:if>` a class.

XML:

```
<row type="header">
 <column type="hidden">href</column>
 <column type="hidden">mNr</column>
 <column type="number">vNr</column>
 <column type="text">description</column>
 <column type="text">document</column>
 <column type="date">date</column>
</row>
```

Wanted output:

```
<tr>
 <th>
  <a class="sortingArrow" onclick="sort(this)">
   vNr
  </a>
 </th>
 <th>
  <a onclick="sort(this)">
   description
  </a>
 </th>
 <th>
  <a onclick="sort(this)">
   document
  </a>
 </th>
 <th>
  <a onclick="sort(this)">
   date
  </a>
 </th>
</tr>
```

XSLT used:

```
<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']/column" mode="columnsone" >
 <xsl:if test="(column[@type!='hidden'])[1]">
  <th>
   <a class="sortingArrow" onclick="sort(this)">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </a>
  </th>
 </xsl:if>
<!-- some other if statement -->
</xsl:template>
```

It is about both of the `<xsl:if>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using templates like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="column[not(@type = 'hidden')][position() = 1]">
    <th>
        <a class="sortingArrow" onclick="sort(this)">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </th>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="column[not(@type = 'hidden')][position() != 1]">
    <th>
        <a onclick="sort(this)">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </th>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="column[not(@type = 'hidden')]"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only outputting nodes that don't have a `type` of "hidden", consider putting the condition as part of the match attribute

```
<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']/column[not(@type='hidden')]" >
```

Note, you would also need a separate template to match ones with a `type` of "hidden".

Then to check if this is the first occurrence of a "non-hidden" element, you would do this:

```
 <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::column[not(@type='hidden')])">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']/column[@type='hidden']" />

<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']/column[not(@type='hidden')]" >
  <th>
   <a onclick="sort(this)">
     <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::column[not(@type='hidden')])">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">sortingArrow</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:if>
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </a>
  </th>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, there is a difference between doing `not(@type='hidden')` and `@type!='hidden'`. In the former case (with the `not`) this will return true if the element does not have a `type` attribute. In the later case, it will return false as it is also checking for the existence of a `type` attribute as well as checking the value.

Comment: From your latest paragraph, It seems to me that I need `@type!="hidden"`, don't I?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="column[not(@type='hidden')]" mode="columnsone"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column" mode="columnsone">
    <th>
        <a onclick="sort(this)">
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">sortingArrow</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </th>
</xsl:template>
```